# Center text above CSS animated underline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 nav menu where I am using some css to show an outward animated underline for the nav-link items. How do I center the text so that the text for the nav-links so that the text is centered above the line?

I tried using `text-align: center` and it did not work I also tried `justify-content: center` but that also did not work. Thank you.

```css
/* CSS */

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 2em;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover::before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Markup -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">EU34</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Support Tracker</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Rolling Log</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a padding on the right side of the link (`padding-right: 2em;`) but no padding on the left side. The `text-align` ignores the space caused by the `padding`.

You can make the padding equal on both sides of the link to center the text with `text-align`.

```css
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover::before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">EU34</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Support Tracker</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Rolling Log</a></li>                
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  .navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
      text-align: center;
      padding-right: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the `padding-right: 2em;` you are using on the link. Because of that, you are creating space on the right side of the link.

If you want to space out the links and have the underline center under the text, use `margin` on both sides instead.